# return array in PHP, Symfony 4 for REST API

Tags: php, arrays

I create my api restoration in symfony 4, but the array I return does not look like I want to.

Below I present my code, resultalt that is currently being performed and at the bottom is the result that I am trying to do.

Can I ask someone for help? I am not entirely sure how to achieve this effect.

This is my service php:

```
$data = $repository->findByData($fromDate, $toDate);

        $i = 1;
        $j = 1;

        $resultArray = [];

        foreach ($data as $key => $d) {
            $date = $d['date'];
            $dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            $resultIteration[$key] = [

                    'customerID' => $d['id'],
                    'customerName' => $d['customerName'],
                    'data' => [
                        'ordersAmount' . $i++ => $d['ordersAmount'],
                        'earnings' . $i++ => $d['earnings'],
                        'date' => $dateString,
                    ],
                    'ordersAmount' . $j++ => $d['ordersAmount'],
                    'earnings' . $j++ => $d['earnings'],

            ];

            array_push($resultArray,$resultIteration[$key]);

        }

return $resultArray;
```

Current result:

```
[
    {
        "customerID": 1,
        "customerName": "Client1",
        "data": {
            "ordersAmount1": 10,
            "earnings2": 882.53,
            "date": "2019-02-21"
        },
        "ordersAmount1": 10,
        "earnings2": 882.53
    },
    {
        "customerID": 1,
        "customerName": "Client1",
        "data": {
            "ordersAmount3": 18,
            "earnings4": 21,
            "date": "2019-02-20"
        },
        "ordersAmount3": 18,
        "earnings4": 21
    },
    {
        "customerID": 2,
        "customerName": "Client2",
        "data": {
            "ordersAmount5": 43,
            "earnings6": 11,
            "date": "2019-02-21"
        },
        "ordersAmount5": 43,
        "earnings6": 11
    },
    {
        "customerID": 2,
        "customerName": "Client2",
        "data": {
            "ordersAmount7": 21,
            "earnings8": 41,
            "date": "2019-02-20"
        },
        "ordersAmount7": 21,
        "earnings8": 41
    }
]
```

I would like to this result:

```
[
    {
      customerID: 1,
      customerName: "Client1",
      data: [
        {
          date: "2019-02-20"
        },
        {
          date: "2019-02-21"
        }
      ],
       ordersAmount1: 12,
       earnings2: 3333,
       ordersAmount3: 1,
       earnings4: 2,
    },
    {
      customerID: 2,
      customerName: "Client2",
      data: [
        {
          date: "2019-02-20"
        },
          date: "2019-02-21"
        }
      ],
      ordersAmount1: 3112,
      earnings2: 44,
      ordersAmount3: 121,
      earnings4: 2543,
    }
  ],
```

Edit: this is my $data:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2019-02-21T00:00:00+01:00",
        "ordersAmount": 10,
        "earnings": 882.53,
        "id": 1,
        "customerName": "Client1"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-02-20T00:00:00+01:00",
        "ordersAmount": 18,
        "earnings": 21,
        "id": 1,
        "customerName": "Client1"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-02-21T00:00:00+01:00",
        "ordersAmount": 43,
        "earnings": 11,
        "id": 2,
        "customerName": "Client2"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-02-20T00:00:00+01:00",
        "ordersAmount": 21,
        "earnings": 41,
        "id": 2,
        "customerName": "Client2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please show the content of `$data` before its processing.

Comment: @Jeto, of course. I edited my post.

Comment: Why do you actually want to remove those quotes from your object keys?

Comment: @epixilog, I want to transform my array in the way I showed it.

Comment: Just to be sure, you *want* the keys to have an ever increasing index such as `ordersAmount1`, `earnings2`, `ordersAmount3`, `earnings4`, etc. rather than arrays? That's very weird and seems unpractical so just asking to be certain.

Comment: @cedada31 I understood that you want it the way you showed it. My question was why you want it that way: is it just for the form? or maybe you're trying to use it somewhere (javascript) and think that you need to remove those quotes?

Comment: @Jeto, yes. I want to use iteration there. i++ BUT always a new client must have a new iteration

Answer (score 0):

See below code, It'll Solve your issue

```
$data = $repository->findByData($fromDate, $toDate);

// define $resultIteration array
$resultIteration = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $d) {
    $i = 1;
    $date = $d['date'];

    //$dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $dateString = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

    $resultIteration[$key] = [
        'customerID' => $d['id'],
        'customerName' => $d['customerName'],
        'data' => [
            [
                'date' => $dateString,
            ], [
                'date' => $dateString
            ]
        ],
        'ordersAmount' . $i++ => $d['ordersAmount'],
        'earnings' . $i++ => $d['earnings'],
        'ordersAmount' . $i++ => $d['ordersAmount'],
        'earnings' . $i++ => $d['earnings'],
    ];

    // REMOVE THIS LINE
    //array_push($resultArray,$resultIteration[$key]);
}

// RETURN $resultIteration in response
return $resultIteration;
```

Comment: No, this don't Solve my issue

Comment: Can you please share response whatever you get?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, using `array_reduce` and `array_map`:

```
$data_by_customer = array_reduce($data, function ($result, $entry) {
  $result[$entry['id']][] = $entry;
  return $result;
}, []);

$result = array_values(array_map(function ($customer_entries) {
  $first_entry = reset($customer_entries);
  $entry = [
    'customerID' => $first_entry['id'],
    'customerName' => $first_entry['customerName'],
    'data' => []
  ];
  $index = 0;
  foreach ($customer_entries as $customer_entry) {
    $entry += [
      'ordersAmount' . ++$index => $customer_entry['ordersAmount'],
      'earnings' . ++$index => $customer_entry['earnings'],
    ];
    $entry['data'][] = ['date' => $customer_entry['date']->format('Y-m-d')];
  }
  return $entry;
}, $data_by_customer));
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/BStNF**

Comment: `DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: @cedada31 Didn't read my comment below the sample? You can change that line to simply `$customer_entry['date']->format('Y-m-d')` in your case. I've edited the answer, just leaving the demo version on 3v4l.org now.

Comment: I would like to remove keys "1"... "2"... etc. and my dates should be objects

Comment: @cedada31 See the updated version and demo (added `array_values` call).